# Count number of invocations of HashMap/HashTable

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

I have a java progam in which there are a lot of HashMap/HashTable being used for mapping key-value pairs. Now I want to profile or rather count how many times the get() and put() methods have been called in my program.

The approach which I was taking is that I extend the Java HashMap/HashTable classes and introduce a member called count and in the get() and the put() methods increment the count everytime the method gets invoked. This would involve a lot of refactoring as I would have to go and remove all the instantiations of the HashMap/HashTables to instead instantiate my extended class. Is this approach reasonable or is there other better way of maintaining this count?

Comment: I think you could do this with reflection and inserting hooks on methods.  Initial googling suggests it's possible, at least.

Comment: God bless search & replace all! :P

Comment: @bdares Could you elaborate on the reflection aspect (I understand Reflection) on how it would be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution for such a task is to use a Profiler such as [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/) or [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html). A profiler performs ["instrumentation"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) on all (or a subset of) the classes loaded by the profiled JVM to perform exactly what you need: Count and measure all of the method invocations, without a single line of modified code.

Both of the aforementioned profilers ship with trial licenses. Once you have tried them, you'll probably buy one because they are very useful in so many situations.

Comment: +1 This is best approach. If this is not an option you can modify HashMap or Hashtable for testing purposes.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I agree this is the best approach but not an option right now. I think I will go ahead and modify the HashMap|HashTable and continue the way I was going about it.

Comment: To modify the original you need to pre-pend them to your bootclasspath or add them to a jar in the `lib/endorsed` directory

Answer (score 0):

You can use profiling tools which will tell you how many times a method is run and how long it takes for the code to be executed. For example, you can do this in the Eclipse IDE: http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tptp.performance

Answer (score -1):

You may use inheritance : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
          HashMap<Integer,Integer> mymap = new myMap<Integer,Integer>();
          mymap.put(3,4);
          mymap.put(5,6);
          System.out.println(mymap.get(3));//this will print 4;
          System.out.println(mymap.getCountGets());//this will print 1 
          System.out.println(mymap.getCountPuts());//this will print 2
    }
}
class myMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V> {

public myMap(){
    countPuts = 0;
    countGets = 0;
}
private int countPuts, countGets ;

@Override
public V put(K k, V v){
    countPuts++;
    return super.put(k, v);
}
@Override
public V get(Object k){
    countGets++;
    return super.get(k);
}

public int getCountGets(){
    return countGets;
}

public int getCountPuts(){
    return countPuts;
}
```

}

Comment: You need to explain your answer.

Comment: inheritance is an OOP concept to make use of the super class's behaviors ,not only that but modifying it also(Overriding).